# "Symbolic" relation between moments and cumulants

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, moment-generating-functions, formal-power-series, cumulants

In the book "Series Expansion Methods" by Oitmaa, Hamer, and Zheng, Appendix 6, they define a moment $\left<\,\,\right>$ as the average of a set of variables, and then define the cumulant $\left[\,\,\,\right]$ as follows

> \begin{equation}\left<\alpha\cdots\zeta\right>=\sum_{P}\left[\alpha\cdots\beta\right]\left[\gamma\cdots\zeta\right]\tag{1}
> \end{equation}
>
> where the sum goes over all possible partitions $P$ of the set of
>   variables, or symbolically
>
> $$\left<\,\,\right> = \sum_{n=1}^\infty
>  \frac{1}{n!}\left[\,\,\,\right]^n\tag{2}$$
>
> For example,
>
> \begin{align*} \left<\alpha\right>&=[\alpha]\\
> \left<\alpha\beta\right>&=[\alpha\beta]+[\alpha][\beta] \\
> \left<\alpha\beta\gamma\right>&=[\alpha\beta\gamma]+[\alpha\beta][\gamma]+[\beta\gamma][\alpha]
>  + [\gamma\alpha][\beta]+[\alpha][\beta][\gamma] \tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> [which] can be inverted to give symbolically
>
> $$\left[\,\,\,\right] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\left<\,\,\right>^n\tag{4}$$
>   for example
>   \begin{align*}
> [\alpha]&=\left<\alpha\right>\\
> [\alpha\beta]&=\left<\alpha\beta\right>-\left<\alpha\right>\left<\beta\right>\\
> [\alpha\beta\gamma]&=\left<\alpha\beta\gamma\right>-\left<\alpha\beta\right>\left<\gamma\right>-\left<\beta\gamma\right>\left<\alpha\right>
>  - \left<\gamma\alpha\right>\left<\beta\right>+2\left<\alpha\right>\left<\beta\right>\left<\gamma\right>\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

These "symbolic" equations are quite mystifying to me. I see how to make the inversion by identifying the first as $e^{[\,]}-1$ and obtaining the second by expanding $\ln(1+\left<\,\,\right>)$, but I don't understand how to interpret either of these equations to write down the corresponding expressions as given, since it is not clear to me what $[\,\,\,]^n$ and $\left<\,\,\right>^n$ mean.

I would like to understand

(a) what is the relationship between equations (1) and (2),

(b) how "rigorous" is the relationship between equations (2) and (4), and

(c) how am I to interpret equation (4) to obtain expressions in (5) (and the same for (2) and (3))

Note I'm a physicist (not a mathematician per se), and this seems incredibly hand-waving to me, but also rather elegant. I have seen more "proper" definitions of cumulants in terms of generating functions.

Comment: Not sure, but you seem to be relating the $[]$ and the $\langle \rangle$ without having properly defined any of them.

Comment: @Daniel they are not defined any further than this in the Appendix, which is only about one page. The above is the primary content and I didn't leave out any definitions.